# IE6 and IE7 Save The Web Pop Up...a simple js file exist?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I've been tasked with bringing a site up-to-date with modern standards. After reading the website statistics, I realized that there's still a significant minority (almost 10%) using IE6 and IE7.

Thankfully I have been given creative freedom on this project. Given this freedom, are you aware of a simple javascript pop-up or library I can use to alert the user that their browser is desperately out of date? Preferably something that has easy to understand instructions.

Many thanks to the future answers. You are saving the web.

Comment: Suggesting to a site user that they should update their browser has always been a big no-no in the past as everyone should be entitled to use whatever browser they like. Perhaps it is acceptable these days with IE6 (and IE7??)? However, do you think an IE6 user is using IE6 out of choice? I would have said most IE6 users are perhaps stuck within a corporate environment and probably have very little choice about what browser they use, so suggesting they should upgrade could just be falling on deaf ears and only serve as an annoyance. Just my opinion.

Comment: In particular instance I would give it an OK because it's a blog and media site, and if a user is being forced to use IE6 then I would go as far to say they probably shouldn't be on the site anyways :) ...we are supporting IE8 and above so the average user will have options to upgrade (and we included instructions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It will also help you provide support / target old browser when developing using HTML5.

To create a unsupported message:

Your html file:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>

    <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(".close-warning").click(function(){
        $(".browser-warning").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .browser-warning {
        display: none;
        background: yellow;
        width: 100%;
        border-top: solid 1px #999;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
     }
    /* Target old browsers with modernizr */
    .oldie .browser-warning {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
        <div class="browser-warning">
            You are using an outdated browser. Please upgrade now to a modern browser in order to benefit of all our site's features:
            <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">Chrome</a>,
            <a href="http://getfirefox.com">FireFox</a>,
            <a href="http://www.opera.com/download/">Opera</a>, 
            <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/">Safari</a> or 
            <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie">Internet Explorer</a>.  
            [<a class="close-warning" href="#">Close</a>]
        </div>
    [...]
    </html>
```

It's tested and it should do the trick.

---

Edited:

Or you can use a simple JS from www.browser-update.org (but the JS file is on their server).

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var $buoop = {} 
   $buoop.ol = window.onload; 
   window.onload=function(){ 
      try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
      var e = document.createElement("script"); 
      e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
      e.setAttribute("src", "http://browser-update.org/update.js"); 
      document.body.appendChild(e); 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Browser update is absolutely beautiful. And I was unaware of Modernizr, a very helpful answer thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of need, I usually use jQuery and its valuable [browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) and [support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) methods. Used together, they are a very convenient way to check for browser version and/or discrete capabilities.

I don't know if you already use jQuery on your project but if it's the case, you have all that you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example at http://www.fotochat.com

Can't remember the usee script but it is one way to do that...